# PHP scandir in windows server

Tags: php, scandir

I'm working on a windows server and I want to use scandir in folder "temp_orders". I echo the full path and I got

```
       "C:\Domains\oaxiscom\oaxis.com\wwwroot\groupon_redeem"
```

its using backwardslash instead of forward and I cannot read the contents inside temp_orders if I scandir

```
       "C:\Domains\oaxiscom\oaxis.com\wwwroot\groupon_redeem\temp_orders"
```

- this creates syntax error coz of "\". any help?

Answer (score 3):

Try `\\` instead of `\`, and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Practically every time where I have needed a path in Windows programming, I was able to use either the forward slash (`/`) or the backwards slash (`\`) between path folder/file names.

Since the backwards slash is used as an escape sequence starting character in so many programming languages, using the forward slash in path names is pretty standard with me these days.

So you could try using forwards slash (`/`) instead of backwards slash.

Since a backwards slash is interpreted by php as an escape, if you use two backwards slashes (`\\`), normally the two are replaced by a single backwards slash when the string is processed by the interpreter.

The backwards slash is also used to insert a quote into a quoted string (`\'` or `\"`) along with some other special characters such as new line character (`\n`).